# Remove repository commits without affecting the bandwith when pushing/pulling

Tags: git

A Git repository is maintained by a single user with:

- 10 GB of size
- 1000 commits
- the first commit is about 1 GB of size, all other commits are about 10 MB of size
- the working directory contains 500 files, 400 of them are in the first commit (**950 MB**), 100 others (10 MB) are changed in other commits
- 100 other users pull changes (no push) made by the maintainer.

How will the maintainer remove all commits and keep a single commit (for many reasons: reduce the repo size, remove sensible files, history is not important anymore ...) avoiding to push big 1 GB commit and avoiding the users to pull a big 1 GB as long as they almost have all files in their repositories and working directories (**950 MB**)?

Comment: I guess you could amend a single commit that you keep in the branch in the repo and amend then force-push every time you want to change something so that the branch only has a single commit there. The downstream uses will then have to fetch then checkout the remote branch (pulling **won't** work because you are removing the old history). Not the most beautiful thing to see... or even desired to do with git _but_ it should work.

Comment: If you're storing files that are auto-generated or contain binary data, you should probably be using Git LFS to track those files. E.g. run `git lfs track '*.jpg'` - if they're JPEG files. Rule of thumb is "If you didn't write it by hand, don't check it in. If you still need to track it, use LFS."

Answer (score 2):

> history is not important anymore...

Since you do not care about the history of the repo, one solution may be to delete all the git info of the repo and initialize the directory again as an entirely new repo. That way, all of the history will be deleted and the directory can be modified in any way before re-initialization.

Git commands to do this:

```
# first create the remote repository on GitHub

# cd to the directory and remove all previous unwanted git information
$ rm -rf .git

# modify the files in any way you want and then initialize a new repository
$ git remote add <remotename> <remote url>  # connect the local repo to the remote repo. Note that <remotename> is usually 'origin'
$ git init
$ git add .
$ git branch -M main                        # create a main branch
$ git commit -m "<init message>"
$ git push <remotename> <branchname>        # push to remote repo
```

> avoiding to push big 1 GB commit and avoiding the users to pull a big 1 GB as long as they almost have all files in their repositories and working directories

I presume that this means you only want to pull the modified files.
To list files that are different in the local repo from the remote repo, run

```
$ git diff --name-only <remotename> <branchname>
```

the output will be a list of files. The following line will get put the files into one line separated by spaces.

```
$ git diff --name-only origin main | sed 's/.*/&/' | paste -sd' ' -
```

Finally, to checkout those files, run the following command

```
$ git checkout main -- $(git diff --name-only origin main | sed 's/.*/&/' | paste -sd' ' -)
```

You can add an alias to you `.bashrc` to make it more convenient:

```bash
alias mpull="git checkout main -- $(git diff --name-only origin main | sed 's/.*/&/' | paste -sd' ' -)"
```

Comment: with that you cannot `avoiding to push big 1 GB commit and avoiding the users to pull a big 1 GB as long as they almost have all files in their repositories and working directories (950 MB)?`

Comment: Your alias call has a bug in it; use `'\''` inplace of `'` when inserting into single-quoted strings, e.g. `alias foo='echo '\''single-quoted'\'' ; morecmds'`

Comment: `git diff --name-only origin main` does not work, I think you must fetch before and fetching is bad for bandwith

Answer (score 1):

### Clone's `--depth` option can help

If your goal is to minimize bandwidth, just force cloners to use `git clone --depth=1 https://...` when cloning your repo.

### Branch butchery

You can start a branch from scratch (I.e. thwack the current branch to containing only 1 commit containing a snapshot of all files in their current state) with this command:

```bash
git reset --soft "$(git rev-list --max-parents=0 HEAD |head -1)"
git commit --amend
```

This of course will completely ignore and not touch any untracked changes in your current working directory. You'll have to `add` and/or `commit` them separately if you want to reflect those changes in your branch.

You'll have to force-push after this.

### Why are you doing this?

Frankly, this shouldn't have happened if you weren't abusing Git.

A good rule of thumb for all revision control systems is:

> If you didn't write it by hand, don't check it in.

If you're storing files that are auto-generated or contain binary data, you should probably be using Git LFS to track those files. E.g. run `git lfs track '*.jpg'` - if they're JPEG files. This can be tricky if you haven't been doing this **from the start**.